# Merge into and add [online-storage] as a synonym of [cloud-storage]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

First, a question: [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) and [cloud-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) mean the same thing, right?

If so, should we merge into and add [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) (12 questions) as a synonym of  [cloud-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) (8 questions)?

Granted, [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) has slightly more questions than [cloud-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) but, in my opinion, the Internet and world of technology is moving away from the term "online storage" towards "cloud storage".

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been completed.

All questions with the [cloud-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-storage) tag have now been converted to the [online-storage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-storage) tag and a synonym has been created.

Answer (score 5):

Marketing and buzzwords are trying to get "cloud storage" as its star. But on a normal fresh user face level, "online storage" still would be their go to term for search.

Would vote to have cloud be a synonym of online.

Stats on which tag brings in more visitors might be helpful.

Throwing those [two terms into a boxing chess match at Google Fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=cloud+storage&word2=online+storage) has **online storage** easily come out far in front.

Right now:

- online storage - 40,600,000 results
- cloud storage - 6,020,000 results

Comment: you make a good point...